# Phonegap Xcode5.1 keyboard done button text is fertig

Tags: ios, cordova, keyboard

I developed many app using phonegap but never had this issue.
Every where in application IOS keyboard "Done" button is changed to "fertig".
I tried and checked everything in app but did not find the issue.My app supports 1 language that is english.
could you suggest why keyboard "Done" button is changed to "fertig" and how can i fix it.
Thanks a ton in advance.
Regards,
Jitendra

Answer (score 1):

"Fertig" is the German term for "done". Make sure that both, your iDevice and Mac as well as the tranlation string is set to English.